# jinja2.exceptions.TemplateSyntaxError: Encountered unknown tag 'type'

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, flask

Trying to execute python function in HTML but receiving the following error:

**ERROR**

```
jinja2.exceptions.TemplateSyntaxError
jinja2.exceptions.TemplateSyntaxError: Encountered unknown tag 'type'.
```

**CODE**

```
<p>Hi, this is a para {{ type(res) }}</p>
```

**CODE EXPLANATION**

It just a para that is receiving `res` dictionary and displaying here. When I am trying to display the whole dictionary it runs well, when displaying a specific value of dictionary it displays nothing, and when finding the type of variable it shows an error.

Answer (score 0):

You can return it as a variable with flask.

```
return render_template('template.html',res_type=type(res))
```

and in HTML:

```
<p>Out:{{res_type}}</p>
```